# Represent date/time periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm working on a booking platform which has several different rates. These rates are determined by the time of day, day of week, and day of year. Here are some examples of the interval types involved:

- Monday to Friday, 9am to 5pm
- Saturday and Sunday, 12am to 9am
- Saturday and Sunday, 9am to 5pm
- Saturday and Sunday, 5pm to 12am
- December 23rd & 24th, anytime
- December 26th & 27th, anytime

What is the best way to represent this, such that it's possible to query for the different effective rates on any given day?

At the moment, the way I've done is using two array type columns, `days_of_week[]` and `hours_of_day[]`, populating them with the days/hours each rate applies. To account for special cases like December, I also have fields `valid_from` and `invalid_after`, however this requires a new entry for each year.

I've had a look at the datetime functions for intervals and such [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) but haven't seen anything that looks like it could solve this.

Comment: See tstzrange in [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html).

Comment: tstzrange looks like it's for ranges of a specific interval (e.g. 10th Jan to 20th) rather than a more generic 10th to 20th of any month

Comment: and multiple OR in where does not work?

Answer (score 0):

why not just listing them in where clause? eg for first sample:

```
t=# select now(),extract('dow' from now()) between 1 and 5 and now()::time between '09:00' and '17:00';
              now              | ?column?
-------------------------------+----------
 2017-11-27 16:56:01.544642+00 | t
```

so you take `(extract('dow' from now()) between 1 and 5 and now()::time between '09:00' and '17:00')` to brackets and add same brackets over `OR`...

You can addthem all to a function with timestamptz as argument and return true of false to use in where clause